# Random Numbers Not Printing Out

Tags: java, random, system.out

I'm having an odd problem here. Not sure what the cause is. I'm writing in Java for a speech demonstration, and I'm writing a few simple programs. For some reason, it doesn't always want to return my random number when working with a rock paper scissors program. My starting code is below, and I want to say that one out of every 3 times, it'll actually print out a number.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
System.out.println(randomNum);
```

Like I said, very simple code, but I have no clue as to why it is only sometimes printing out numbers...

Edit: Entire Project

Main
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Speech_Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean running = true;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        while(running){
            if(in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                running = false;
            }
            if(in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Hello_World")){
                Hello_World.start();
            }
            if(in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("rps")){
                Rock_Paper_Scissors.start();
            }
        }
        in.close();
        return;
}

}
```

RPS

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Rock_Paper_Scissors {
public static void start(){
    System.out.println(random());
}
private static int random(){

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt() + 1;
    return randomNum;
}
}
```

Comment: it will print no between 1-3.What the issue ??

Comment: It always prints a number for me. Why wouldn't it? Maybe there's something else you're doing which you are not showing us here.

Comment: I don't know if its my laptop or not. But I've ran it within eclipse, and exported it and ran from command prompt. It only gives me a result every 3 times I call it.

Comment: Can you post your `main`'s method code? Or the whole test class code?

Comment: @Kristoff do one thing run this code in infinite loop and print the values.U will find all the possible value.It will be between 1 to 3.

Comment: I just edited the question with the rest of the code. Yes, I know I get numbers between 1-3. That's not the problem. The problem is that it only prints out a result every 3 times the method is called. I have to type in rps 3 times to get a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that each time in your loop, you call `in.next()` three times:

```
    while(running){
        if(in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
            running = false;
        }
        if(in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Hello_World")){
            Hello_World.start();
        }
        if(in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("rps")){
            Rock_Paper_Scissors.start();
        }
    }
```

When you get to the first `if`, you call `in.next()`, which gets the next token from the scanner.  The problem is that when you get to the second `if`, it will call `in.next()` **again**, which will then try to get another token.  It doesn't use the previous one, because you've told it to get a new one.  To fix this, declare a variable to hold `in.next()` at the beginning of the loop:

```
String input = in.next();
```

and then check the variable.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a simple problem. I'm just writing this up as a BS program for a speech, and didn't realize that.